# Connect from external list from different site collections via OData in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, external-content-type, app, odata

I am using SharePoint Online and I have followed the steps of the [tutorial](https://lightningtools.com/bcs/sharepoint-online-odata-bcs/):

But the OData service url was the list of the second site collection.

https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site Collection 2/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/

And I am getting the forbidden error, once the app initializes.

Another way I have tried was by uploading the **ect** file generated on Visual Studio and follow the tutorial in http://www.sharepointconsultant.ch/2013/11/09/consuming-an-external-odata-service-from-an-sharepoint-2013-app/

The difference is that I didn't find a way of making the **step 11** on SharePoint Powershell, but I did it using the UI. But in anyway it didn't work.

I am getting the forbidden message as well.

Comment: You App is allowed to run in SiteCollection A. It would be a huge security issue if it could access SiteCollections B,C,D without approval. It is like your housekeeper.. he gets the keys to your house, and can't access the neighbors house.

Comment: But is there a way to approve it on other site collections on the same tenant ? I would need to install two instances of the same app in different site collections ?